# can i scroll to specific section of my landing page when visiting it directly throught URL [Nextjs]

Tags: next.js

What I want to do is navigate to specific section in the landing page when the user access it directly with the URL i.e(localhost:3000/faqs)

I tried to use many solutions:  but it always redirects to 404 page

```
import DefaultLayout from "@Components/DefaultLayout";
import {
  JoinCommunity,
  LandingBanner,
  MixMatch,
  OnlinePresence,
  LandingFaqs,
} from "@Components/LandingPage";
import { NextPage } from "next";
import { RIA } from "@Constants/acl";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import useTranslation from "next-translate/useTranslation";
import withGuard from "@Hocs/withGuard";
import { SocialProfileJsonLd } from "next-seo";
import { generatePageSeo, getFullURL } from "@Utils/Seo";

interface Props {
  ACL: {
    action: string;
  };
}

const LandingPage: NextPage<Props> = () => {
  const { locale, asPath } = useRouter();
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");
  const completeURL = getFullURL(asPath, locale);

  return (
    <DefaultLayout
      showFooter
      showLandingNav
      fullWidth
    >
 
      <LandingBanner />
      <OnlinePresence />
      <MixMatch />
      <JoinCommunity />
      <LandingFaqs />
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
};

LandingPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {
    ACL: {
      action: RIA,
    },
  };
};

export default withGuard(LandingPage);
```

so i want to know if there any way to do this or not

Comment: can you make a dummy example here? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-greider-4lhnwh?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A20%2C32

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about my problem, I think I was overengineering the solution
so what i did i created another page called faqs under pages directory
and it's content is the same as the landing page and perform scrolling behaviour in it

```
import DefaultLayout from "@Components/DefaultLayout";
import {
  JoinCommunity,
  LandingBanner,
  MixMatch,
  OnlinePresence,
  LandingFaqs,
} from "@Components/LandingPage";
import { NextPage } from "next";
import { RIA } from "@Constants/acl";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import useTranslation from "next-translate/useTranslation";
import withGuard from "@Hocs/withGuard";
import { SocialProfileJsonLd } from "next-seo";
import { generatePageSeo, getFullURL } from "@Utils/Seo";
import { createRef, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";

interface Props {
  ACL: {
    action: string;
  };
}

const LandingPage: NextPage<Props> = () => {
  const { locale, asPath } = useRouter();
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");
  const completeURL = getFullURL(asPath, locale);

  const faqsRef = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (faqsRef.current) {
      console.log("scrolling to faqs", faqsRef.current);
      faqsRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest" });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <DefaultLayout
      showFooter
      showLandingNav
      fullWidth
      seoData={generatePageSeo(
        t("seo-landing-title"),
        locale,
        asPath,
        `${t("reach-link-head")} | %s`,
        t("seo-landing-desc"),
      )}
    >

      <LandingBanner />
      <OnlinePresence />
      <MixMatch />
      <JoinCommunity />
      <div ref={faqsRef}>
        <LandingFaqs />
      </div>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
};

LandingPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {
    ACL: {
      action: RIA,
    },
  };
};

export default withGuard(LandingPage);
```